# C# How to define a variable as global within a (Step Defintion) class

Tags: variables, global

below is an extract from a Step Definition class of my Specflow project.

In the first method **public void WhenIExtractTheReferenceNumber()** I can successfully extract the text from the application under test, and I have proved this using the Console.WriteLine();

I need to be able to use this text in other methods with in my class **I.e. public void WhenIPrintNumber();** But I'm not sure how to do this!

I read about Get/Set but I could not get this working. So I'm thinking is it possible to make my **var result** global somehow, so that I can call it at anytime during the test?

```
namespace Application.Tests.StepDefinitions
    {
        [Binding]
        public class AllSharedSteps
        {

        [When(@"I extract the reference number")]
        public void WhenIExtractTheReferenceNumber()
        {
            Text textCaseReference = ActiveCase.CaseReferenceNumber;
            Ranorex.Core.Element elem = textCaseReference;
            var result = elem.GetAttributeValue("Text");
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }

        [When(@"I print number")]
        public void WhenIPrintNumber()
        {
            Keyboard.Press(result);                
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any thoughts.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the framework you're using, but it seems to me you could just make `result` a static member of the `AllSharedSteps` class.  You might need to assign its value from within a static constructor of the class, so that it doesn't matter which tests you run and in which order.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the *solution* to my question. Now I can access my variable(s) from any methods within my class. I have also included code that I'm using to split my string and then use the first part of the string. In my case I need the numerical part of **'12345 - some text'**:

```
namespace Application.Tests.StepDefinitions
{
    [Binding]
    public class AllSharedSteps
    {
        private string result;
        public Array splitReference;

        [When(@"I extract the case reference number")]
        public void WhenIExtractTheCaseReferenceNumber()
        {            
            Text textCaseReference = ActiveCase.CaseReferenceNumber;
            Ranorex.Core.Element elem = textCaseReference;
            result = elem.GetAttributeValue("Text").ToString();
            splitReference = result.Split('-');  // example of string to be split '12345 - some text'
            Console.WriteLine(splitReference.GetValue(0).ToString().Trim());
        }

        [When(@"I print number")]
        public void WhenIPrintNumber()
        {
            Keyboard.Press(result);  // prints full string
            Keyboard.Press(splitReference.GetValue(0).ToString());  // prints first part of string i.e. in this case, a reference number
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this help somebody else :)